# Excel: Creating a Sequential ID (values in excel + next number in criteria sequence)

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is probably a simple one but I have been looking at it for too long now.

I am trying to create a formula that will generate a Unique Property ID using a Country Code + Property Type Code + the next available number in the sequence (meeting the Country Code + Property Type Code criteria). Any advice would be much appreciated!

| Property Name | Country Code | Property Type Code | Unique Property ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Property 1 | 01 | 1 | 01-101 |
| Property 2 | 02 | 1 | 02-101 |
| Property 3 | 03 | 1 | 03-101 |
| Property 4 | 02 | 3 | 02-301 |
| Property 5 | 02 | 3 | 02-302 |
| Property 6 | 01 | 1 | 01-102 |
| Property 7 | 01 | 3 | 01-301 |
| Property 8 | 03 | 1 | 03-102 |

Answer (score 0):

If your Property Type value isn't going above 9 then this formula should work (note the references to column D are absolute to one row above data, and relative to row above formula):

```
=LET(Prefix, B3 & "-" & C3,
          DataTable, FILTER(D$1:D2,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Prefix,D$1:D2)),0),
          Ordinal, SUBSTITUTE(DataTable,Prefix,"")*1,
          NextID, MAX(Ordinal)+1,
          Return, Prefix & TEXT(NextID, "00"),
          Return)
```

[image]